# What event do I need to wait on before calling model.rayIntersect()?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

When calling `model.rayIntersect()` in the Autodesk Forge viewer, I noticed that the intersects returned did not always reflect the accurate intersections unless I wait on the `GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT`.

From inspecting the non-minified source code of the viewer ([here](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.js)) it does not appear to me that waiting on `GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT` is necessary based on any of the operations in the `rayIntersect()` function. It is my understanding that we could get the mesh data of objects in the viewer simply from the fragments, which does not require the `GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT`. Is there another event I could wait on before calling `model.rayIntersect()` that may fire more quickly?

I am working to perform this intersection calculation on large models in a headless form of the viewer, so waiting on the `GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT` can take quite some time, so I would prefer not to wait for it to finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hit-testing logic in Forge Viewer is pretty complex and may use different approaches (such as hit-testing a BVH, hit-testing individual meshes, or checking pixels in an "ID buffer") depending on your environment and settings.

The BVH is computed by the viewer after it receives the "fragment list" with bounding boxes of all fragments (it's an async operation that may take a while), and the ID buffer is generated as part of the standard rendering pipeline, so for these to work, you should actually wait for the `Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_EVENT_LOADED` event.